# Android Spinner: onItemSelected listener is not called when selecting the same item

Tags: android, listener, android-spinner

I have a requirement to show an `AlertDialog` when selecting the 2nd item in `Spinner`. I know that using `onItemSelected` we can listen to the spinner selection & show a popup. The issue is when I select the 2nd item, the dialog appears but after closing the dialog and then again we select the same item, it won't show the dialog as `onItemSelected` will not be invoked. Is there any workaround for this? Without using a custom `Spinner` implementation.

Comment: Post your code.. Questions like these without code will tend people to down vote your question.

Comment: @HarishSridharan while that's true most of the time, this is exactly the type of question where code is not really needed. If you know the situation it's mostly trivial to reconstruct what the OP's code may look like. Having a `Spinner` with a listener that checks the `position` arguments and does something is not a hard thing. I think some poeple downvote questions they don't understand, for some reason.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Thanks..you said what I was supposed to comment..this doesn't require any code to understand. A spinner, its listener & its done.

Comment: @sJy try `spinner.setSelection(Spinner.INVALID_POSITION);` in the listener, so `onItemSelected` always triggers an `onNothingSelected` event too. This means that you'll lose tracking the selected item, but I have a feeling it's not a big deal for this situation. You can also try only calling when `position == 1`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob it didn't work..onNothingSelected is not called in any case..

Comment: @sJy what about the the dialog showing up on second select? That would be the key here.

Comment: @TWiStErRob The answer by Anoop is working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Create a custom spinner***

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class CustomSpinner extends Spinner {
    OnItemSelectedListener listener;
    private AdapterView<?> lastParent;
    private View lastView;
    private long lastId;

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        initlistner();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        if (position == getSelectedItemPosition() && listener != null) {
            listener.onItemSelected(lastParent, lastView, position, lastId);
        } else {
            super.setSelection(position);
        }

    }

    private void initlistner() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                lastParent = parent;
                lastView = view;
                lastId = id;
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onNothingSelected(parent);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void setOnItemSelectedEvenIfUnchangedListener(
            OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}
```

***Set Listener***

```
private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

listener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

***Pass the listener object to custom listener***

```
cusSpinner.setOnItemSelectedEvenIfUnchangedListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thanks..actually I needed if this can be done without custom spinner..I knew a Custom Spinner can easily handle this..

Comment: I am trying to add this feature to react-native but am not sure how to modify it to acheive this, may you please give some tips on the minimal changes I need to make to achieve this in the file here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/picker/ReactPicker.java#L80 - I'm a javascript guy, this is my first venture into java.

Comment: FYR- [ISSUE 15556](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15556)

Comment: How to instantiate cusSpinner ?

Comment: This is working solution, thanks for saving my day

Answer (score -3):

try the code below:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
{
     switch(arg2)
     {
          case 0:
          {
               Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
               .......
               dialog.show();
               spinner.setSelection(0);
          }
          break;
     }
[...]
```

Comment: Please test this code yourself & try whether it works as expected. (This doesn't work)