# Spinner onItemSelected is not called using Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-toolbar

I have a spinner in my app that I implement like this:

```
   //Setup spinner
    spinner = (AppCompatSpinner) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.sections, R.layout.spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_list_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    });
```

This works fine with my phone running API level 19 (4.4.2) but running on Marshmallow, API level 23 (6.0), the onItemSelected is never called.

I've tried with both *android.widget.Spinner* and with *android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner* with the same result.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

[Android Spinner: onItemSelected listener is not called when selecting the same item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742895/android-spinner-onitemselected-listener-is-not-called-when-selecting-the-same-i)

Just create CustomSpinner;

That way solved the problem on Marshmallow;