# Android Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, spinner

Is there a way to execute when the same Position is selected?

For example, if 0 is currently selected, selecting 0 again will cause the same event to occur again.

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31743733/5110595)

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25478178/3999642) . By using you can select already selected item.

Comment: @HemantParmar   How do I apply this to the spinner I have created?

Comment: @RajatMehra How do I apply this to the spinner I have created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Custom Class that extends `Spinner` and replace it with your `Spinner`

```
public class NDSpinner extends Spinner {

    public NDSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NDSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NDSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void
    setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position, animate);
        if (sameSelected) {
            // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
            getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void
    setSelection(int position) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position);
        if (sameSelected) {
            // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
            getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this code to define an extension class. How do you apply this to your existing Spinner?

Comment: Replace `Spinner` with `NDSpinner` in your existing xml and code.